# Loop interval changing unexpectedly

Tags: c++, unix

I am writing a loop to remove every third element from an array until there is only one element left.

here is the code...

```
int elimcnt = 1;//counts how many elements looped through
int cnt = 0;//counts how many elements deleted for printing purposes
for (int i = 0; v.size() > 1; i++, elimcnt++) {
    if (i == v.size()) {//reset i to the beginning when it hits the end
        i = 0;
    }

    if (elimcnt%in.M == 0 && elimcnt != 0) {//in.M is elimination index which is 3
        v.erase(v.begin() + (elimcnt%v.size()) - 1);
        cnt++;
        if (cnt%in.K == 0) {//in.K is how often you will print which is after 7 deletes
            print_vector(v, cnt);
        }
    }
}
```

what actually happens when i run it is that it will correctly delete the first element but after that it deletes every 4th element from there on out.

Here is an example input...

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 B1 B2 B3
B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
C7 C8 C9 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5
```

What is supposed to be outputted...

```
A1 A2 A4 A5 A7 A8 B1 B2 B4 B5 B7 B8
C1 C2 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 D1 D2 D3 D4
D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5
```

This is what is actually outputted...

```
A1 A2 A4 A5 A6 A8 A9 B1 B3 B4 B5 B7
B8 B9 C2 C3 C4 C6 C7 C8 D1 D2 D3 D4
D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5
```

I cant seem to figure out what is causing the code to do this so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _from an array_ an array has no member begin.

Comment: If v is a vector, erase _Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator_ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase and as one can imagine, the size changes too.

Comment: Instead of mangling the vector you're iterating on, why not make a new one and push in the values you want?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the expression used in the statement

```
v.erase(v.begin() + (elimcnt%v.size()) - 1);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Consider a sequence of numbers

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

For the first traversing of the sequence You need to delete `3` and `6`

After deleting 3 you will get

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 6
```

and the variable `elimcnt` after the deleting will be incremented and will be equal to 4. However the size of the sequence is now equal to 5. So when `elimcnt` will be equal to 6 then  the expression `elimcnt%v.size()) - 1` will be equal to 0 and the element 1 will be deleted.

I could suggest a more safe approach using iterators.

for example

```
size_t elimcnt = 0;//counts how many elements looped through
size_t cnt = 0;

for (auto it = v.begin(); v.size() > 1; it == v.end() ? it = v.begin() : it )
{
    if (++elimcnt % in.M == 0)
    {
        it = v.erase(it);

        if (++cnt % in.K == 0)
        {
            print_vector(v, cnt);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```